# SSIS Generate Output Variable from python script using Execute Process Task

Tags: python, ssis

I am trying to build an ssis solution and the first task is to get some information from a particular api trough a python script. I have three statuses which the script can give me: 1. Success 2. Connection Error and 3. No Data

Now what I wish to do is that from the python script i can output the value (success or connError or NoData) and the value is transferred to a variable in the ssis. Based on the variable value then different tasks will be performed.

Is this something that can be done (that is output a variable from python script and save it in ssis as a variable)? If so how can I do it?

Thanks

Comment: Execute process task, not execute _package_ task, correct?

Comment: @billinkc yes that is right ... apologies for the confusion :)